# laravel5－How can i hide the specific column of withPivot?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5

I use belongstomany function to get the models and used withPivot() to get an extra column data in the pivot table. However, the withPivot() function will add the 2 foreign keys in the output json. I want to hide thses keys and only show the column I want to display.

The follwing is my response data

```
{"status_code":"1","next_page":"2","dataset":[{"id":"829","req_start_time":"2016-03-13 14:55:00","req_end_time":"2016-03-13 09:55:00","content":[{"name":"\u9752\u6912\u7092\u725b\u8089","price":"120","pic_url":"","detail":"\u8d85\u7ea7\u597d\u5403\u7684\u54df","pivot":{"waiter_request_id":"829","goods_id":"2","count":"2"}}
```

as you see the pivot json object contains two id keys.
how could i remove them from the object? or some other ways to solve this get the right way of this need?

thx in advance!

---

Now the question already upgraded!

How can I add this 'count' parameter of pivot in the object which belongs to 'content'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,I figured out the right way to solve this problem. Follwing the code:

```
class Goods extends Model{
     ......
     ......

     public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    $pivot = new Pivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    $pivot->addHidden(
        array(
            'waiter_request_id',
            'goods_id'
        )
    );
    return $pivot;
}
}
```

you can rewrite this method to provide a new pivot object to the Model in your **'belongsToMany'**